# Combining Table Aliases with "Where" in Informix

Tags: sql, syntax, where-clause, informix

I'm facing serious problems using table aliases on Informix with a where part.

So I can run:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
  FROM Table1 AS TestTable
```

But as soon as i try this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE type = 'A' AS TestTable
```

..it wouldn't work. The same happens when I try to join tables with a WHERE part.

I'm trying to optimize a query from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077241/sql-stmt-performance-issue-on-informix) so I'm trying not to work with temporary tables.

Comment: You don't alias in the WHERE clause; most databases don't even allow using an alias defined in the SELECT to be used in the WHERE clause.  It's not clear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: I faced this issue as i was tryign the answer of "DRapp" on the original Question (c link above). Sorry for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get the equivalent of Oracle's inline views. Syntax is:

```
select *
from  
   TABLE(MULTISET(SELECT ColA, ColB 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE type = 'A' )) T1
join 
   TABLE(MULTISET(SELECT ColA, ColB 
  FROM Table2 
 WHERE type = 'Z' )) T2 on (t2.colA = t1.colA)
```

Comment: You really don't need the `TABLE(MULTISET(...))` around the SELECT statements.

Comment: What is `TABLE(MULTISET(...))` good for? I would just use `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can alias columns in the select-list or tables (or sub-queries) in the FROM clause.

Therefore, you'd write:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB 
  FROM Table1 AS TestTable
 WHERE type = 'A'
```

or you'd write:

```
SELECT t.*, r.*
  FROM (SELECT ColA, ColB 
          FROM Table1 AS TestTable
         WHERE type = 'A'
       ) AS t
  JOIN AnotherTable AS r ON t.ColA = r.ColC
```

Note that in this query, the name TestTable does not actually get used.  A more complex sub-query might well make use of an alias (though I have a strong preference for short aliases — aliases that are shorter than the table name that is aliassed).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, trying to use an alias in a Where clause is not permitted in any database system. You can push the results of a Select statement into a table using `Select ... Into` like so:

```
Select ColA, ColB Into Table2
From Table1 As TestTable
```

However, you would then need to use a separate SQL statement to use `Table2` in the above example. The other choice is to use a common-table expression which I believe is supported by Informix:

```
With Foo As
    (
    Select ColA, ColB
    From Table1 As TestTable
    )
Select ColA, ColB
From Foo
```